# RequestContext.complete method ask me for Marshaller - Akka Http with Java

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to print a simple post value in High Level Server based on `Akka Http` with `java`, but when I call ContextRequest.complete method, it ask me for Marshaller. (I'm relied on the following [documentation example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/java/http/routing-dsl/request-vals/form-field-request-vals.html#Examples)):

This is my code:

```
FormField<String> event = FormFields.stringValue("event");
final Route route =route(
    handleWith1(event, (ctx, e) ->
        ctx.complete("Event name is " + e)
    )
);
```

Error says:

> complete(String, Marshaller) in RequestContext
>   cannot be applied to (String)

Does anyone know what it can be?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm: are you using Akka 2.4.2? (Just double-checking as the example is for 2.4.2)

Comment: Ok then, much has changed since then. Request values are gone, in favour of directives. This is a relevant example http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/java/http/routing-dsl/directives/form-field-directives/formField.html#formfield-java